# Integrating Java Help System with Windows application

Tags: java, javahelp

I have a Java application for Windows, to which I would like to add a help system.

I have heard about Java help system but I don't have much idea on that and I would like to have to some guidelines and samples on how to integrate it with a Windows application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to have a Window pop-up when help is requested (F1 is pressed at a specific context). This window has a JToolbar and a JSpitPane. The left panel has a JTree used for navigating and the right is a JEditorPane which displays the help HTML pages.

[image]

You can run your own implementation, but the most convenient and standard way of setting up a Java help system is through the JavaHelp System. http://javahelp.java.net/.

"The JavaHelp system is an online help system that developers can use to add online help to their Java platform applications. The JavaHelp system is both a JCP specification (JSR 97) and a reference implementation of that specification. The JavaHelp system open source project includes the source to the reference implementation."

Check also the [JavaHelp 2.0 System User's Guide](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/jhug.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @costis Aivalis  
Also I have got some other links regarding the same issue
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/pkeegan/archive/2007/05/javahelp_and_sw.html